# Invoke a Label Control which is bound to an Object Property located on different thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, binding, invoke

I have two forms Form1 and Form2 ,on the Form1 i have a shared BindingList which will be used by Form2 as well, when a button on Form1 clicked it adds a new object to binding list and opens Form2 on a new thread.

```
 Friend Shared WithEvents AllObjects As New BindingList(Of MyObject)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
           Dim Object1 As New MyObject With {.MyName = "I am One"}
           Dim Object2 As New MyObject With {.MyName = "I am Two"}
           Me.AllObjects.Add(Object1)
           Me.AllObjects.Add(Object2)

           Dim Thread = New Thread(Sub ()
                                   Dim Frm2 As Form2 = New Form2()
                                   Application.Run(Frm2 )
                                   End Sub ))
                    Thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
                    Thread.Start()
    End Sub
```

MyObject Class contains a property which is bound to one of the label on the Form2

```
 Friend Class MyObject
     Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
     Private Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
     Private _myName as String
     Public Property MyName As String
        Get
            Return _myName 
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _myName = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyName"))
        End Set
    End Property


Public Class Form2
    Friend WithEvents MyOwnObject As MyObject 

    Private Sub Form2_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
            MyOwnObject = Form1.AllObjects.Item(0)
            Me.lblName.DataBindings.Add("Text", MyOwnObject , "MyName")

    End Sub
End Class
```

When Form2 is shown the lblMyName label text is successfully showing "I am One" as expected.

The problem starts now on the Form1 i have another button which changes the property of two objects in the binding list located on Form1 but when i do that getting a Cross-Thread Operation not valid exception, have tried to resolve to best of my knowledge but still getting the same error , can anyone help me how i can invoke a Label which is bound to an object located on another thread ?

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
               Me.AllObjects.Item(0).MyName = "I am now Three"
               Me.AllObjects.Item(1).MyName = "I am now Four"
End Sub
```

Comment: "opens Form2 on a new thread". Why?

Comment: as you can see the above code does nothing as i have replicated the issue here as example forms, on the real application the BindingList(of MyObject) will have about 500 items and this is bound to a DataGridView on the form1 , and as and when user double click on any row a second form2 is shown with the object from that row.index, and the displayed form will have couple of labels which are bound to the BindingList object , the objects in the binding list is regularly updated the value which is the market tick data , so basically form2 contains Lavel2 market data ,

Comment: That doesn't explain why you have two forms owned by different threads.

Comment: A user will probably keep open more than 5 quotes which is Form2 and these forms will be keep updating by its underlying object as it is a market tick data + level2 data , so i suspect this might cause the performance issue or delay in getting updated one of the form2 amongst those 5 kept opened. this is the reason made me to open them on its own thread , correct me if i am wrong ?

Comment: You're wrong.  If you want to retrieve data in a secondary thread initiated in those forms then by all means but there's no good reason to own the forms on different threads.